# Help me prove CLT $\implies$ error term in OLS regression is distributed normally

Tags: least-squares, error, central-limit-theorem

How can I prove that the central limit theorem implies that error term in an OLS regression is normally distributed? (A statement to this effect has been mentioned in Econometrics p. 33 by Fumio Hayashi (2000)).

Comment: Under what assumptions about the regression and error term?

Comment: Thank you @Dave. The assumptions are: 1.)  linearity of regression in dep. var; 2.) strict exogeneity of regressors; 3.) no multicollinearity; 4.) homoskedasticity; 5.) no correlation between observations.

Comment: Are the regressors fixed or random?  If random, what do you assume about their distribution?

Comment: The regressors (X) are assumed to be random. Hayashi mentions that no particular distribution needs to be specified for X, especially for hypothesis testing if conditional distribution of error term conditional on X is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear regression model may be written as
$$
y_i=x_i'\beta+u_i
$$

The reference says

> In many applications, the error term consists of many miscellaneous
>   factors not captured by the regressors. The Central Limit Theorem
>   suggests that the error term has a normal distribution.

So, Hayashi asks why $u_i$ ought to be assumed to be normally distributed.

In my understanding, the logic goes as follows:

The error term $u_i$ captures all influences on $y_i$ that are not already accounted for by the regressors $x_i$. Now, you could think of a great many influences that have not been accounted for. Ideally, the important influences have already been included via the regressors, so that $u_i$ captures "unimportant" factors. The CLT roughly says that a suitably scaled average of many small factors behaves like a normal random variables. So, $u_i$, collecting these factors, would be normally distributed.

Personally, I do not find this logic to be too appealing, though. First, we do not need this normality assumption on the errors once we (as does Hayashi later on, see also the second quotation below) resort to asymptotic approximations (as $n\to\infty$), which is pretty much all we can do once we leave this fairly restrictive setup of the linear model anyhow.

Second, I believe the error term $u_i$ is just the error associated with person/observation $i$, and there is exactly one error for that observation. To me, it is quite a stretch of the imagination to interpret that single error as the average of infinitely many "sub-errors" that would justify a CLT. (Letting $n\to\infty$ is far more plausible to me, as we can conceivably collect more data, though.)

Third (also see below), it is unclear why that logic should be applicable in the practically very relevant case of omitted variables (i.e., important factors being left in the error term).

Indeed, in Chapter 2, Hayashi writes

> However, not very often in economics are the assumptions of the exact
>   distribution satisfied. The finite-sample theory breaks down if one of
>   the following three assumptions is violated: (1) the exogeneity of
>   regressors, *(2) the normality of the error term* (my emphasis), and (3) the linearity
>   of the regression equation.

Comment: I agree with your explanation of CLT, but am still left wondering how $u_i$ would be normally distributed, given that it is generally not scaled (or am I wrong here?). Thank you for filling the gaps for me.

Comment: Since it is not really clear what is being averaged over here (viz. unobserved and presumably "unimportant" factors), it is indeed (at least to me) also not clear if these things are scaled or not. To an extent, that question is maybe a little moot if one is willing to refer to the approximative implication of the CLT that the *sum* of r.v.s $\epsilon_j\sim (\mu,\sigma^2)$, $\sum_{j=1}^m\epsilon_j$, then is $N(m\mu,m\sigma^2)$.

Comment: So, in any case, I would argue that there is no such thing as a proof of the statement in the title of your question. I'd rather think of it as a somewhat heuristic justifcation of an assumption.

Comment: Yes, I did not ask for or provide a proof, and your explanation in your first comment above has clarified my doubt on an intuitive level (wish my reputation allowed giving +1). Btw, I think $\sum_{j=1}^m\epsilon_j \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and not $N(m\mu,m\sigma^2)$.

Comment: Actually, if each r.v. has mean $\mu$, then their sum has $m$ times that mean. Think tossing $m$ dice with expectation 3.5 each, and similarly for the variance of the sum of (additionally, uncorrelated) r.v.s.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I was actually thinking "summation" but imagining "mean". Got it now!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as proof that the error term in OLS regression is normally distributed as it's an assumption. It just needs to be stated when we want to test for statistical significance of the $\beta$'s. In fact, the Gauss-Markov theorem doesn't even mention normality of the error term.

What we can do, however, is to conduct model diagnostics (likea q-q plot) in order to verify that such assumption holds.