# OLS Regression: How can the Central Limit Thorem justify the assumption of normality of the error term?

Tags: regression, normality-assumption, central-limit-theorem

Relative noob here.

My understanding is that the CLT is used to derive the sampling distribution of the sample means. So from a population distribution, whether normal or not, if you take a sample and take the mean value of that sample, then these means will be normally distributed.

I’m going to use die rolling as an example to illustrate my question. With CLT, say our sample size is 30, then we roll the die 30 times, take the mean, and then make a histogram of these means. The population and sample mean distributions will look like this (the sample is an Excel simulation of the mean of 3000 samples each of size 30):

[image]

[image]

Each of the 3,000 observations on the Mean of Die rolls chart is actually the mean of 30 rolls and those means will cluster around the population mean, 3.5.

But if instead of taking means, we simply record each single observation and make a histogram of those values, then the resulting distribution would not be normally distributed. In fact, it would be about the same uniform distribution as the parent population (this chart is an Excel simulation of 3000 samples each of the result of a single die roll)

[image]

With OLS, my understanding is that we are carrying out the second sampling exercise, not the first. That is, each observation is not the sample average, but the value for a single observation. If we overlay the distributions of these sample values around the the regression line, which is essentially what the distribution of error terms is, then there is no reason that the distribution should be affected by the CLT, which pertains to sample means.

So why can the CLT be deployed in defence of the assumption of normality of the error terms?

(Also, I know the response to questions about the normality assumption are often that this assumption is not super important and that it is not necessary for estimation, and, also, that in large samples, it is not even so necessary for hypothesis testing. This is all good in practice, but I’d still like to understand the theoretical justification of this assumption).

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470119/help-me-prove-clt-implies-error-term-in-ols-regression-is-distributed-normall

Comment: *"My understanding is that the CLT is used to derive the **sampling** distribution of the sample means. So from a population distribution, whether normal or not, if you take a sample and take the mean value of that sample, then these means will be normally distributed."* - Not the sampling distribution but the asymptotic distribution. For sampling distribution you need to specify the distribution of population.

Comment: CLT does not justify normality of the error terms.

Comment: In Gujarati & Porter, Basic Econometrics, 4th Edition, page 109:
"It is the CLT that provides a theoretical justification for the assumption of normality of ui ."